# How to get number of days from this string field?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table containing the service days in a week for customers. It's currently in a weird string format and I need a way to convert it into a number instead.

```
M T W Th F S Su
M   W      S
    W    F   Su
  T   Th   S Su
      Th
```

So the expected results from that should be

```
7
3
3
4
1
```

I've tried using trim then counting the spaces but the problem is that there could be multiple spaces between the characters. The number of possible different combinations also makes it difficult to use a decode function.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle supports `regexp_count()`, so you can do:

```
select regexp_count('    W    F   Su', '[^ ]+')
from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces, replace `Th` with `T` and `Su` with `S` and count the number of chars:

```
select length(replace(replace(replace(yourcolumn, ' ', ''), 'Th', 'T'), 'Su', 'S'))
from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: remove all spaces, `u` and `h` and check the length of the remaining string:

```
select length(translate(mycol, '. hu', '.')) from dual
```

This will return NULL if no day is set.